# A component required a bean named '' that could not be found

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, spring-security-rest

I'm trying to build my first grails application using grails-spring-security-rest plugin following [this post](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/)'s instructions.

However, when I try to run the application it gives me the following output:

```
| Running application...
2017-05-07 20:18:54.614  WARN --- [           main] g.p.s.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin     : 
Configuring Spring Security Core ...

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
2017-05-07 20:18:54.688  WARN --- [           main] g.p.s.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin     : ... finished configuring Spring Security Core

... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security REST 2.0.0.M2...
... finished configuring Spring Security REST

        ... with GORM support
2017-05-07 20:19:00.278 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Validated configuration attributes
2017-05-07 20:19:00.527 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.r.t.g.jwt.FileRSAKeyProvider       : Loading public/private key from DER files
2017-05-07 20:19:00.531 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.r.t.g.jwt.FileRSAKeyProvider       : Public key path: /mnt/dev/Workspaces/LZR.RAS/RAS-API/security/public_key.der
2017-05-07 20:19:00.538 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.r.t.g.jwt.FileRSAKeyProvider       : Private key path: /mnt/dev/Workspaces/LZR.RAS/RAS-API/security/private_key.der
2017-05-07 20:19:00.612 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter     : Initializing filter 'restTokenValidationFilter'
2017-05-07 20:19:00.612 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter     : Filter 'restTokenValidationFilter' configured successfully
2017-05-07 20:19:00.612 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Initializing filter 'restExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-05-07 20:19:00.612 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Filter 'restExceptionTranslationFilter' configured successfully
2017-05-07 20:19:00.613 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Initializing filter 'filterChainProxy'
2017-05-07 20:19:00.613 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Filter 'filterChainProxy' configured successfully
2017-05-07 20:19:00.613 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.rest.RestLogoutFilter              : Initializing filter 'restLogoutFilter'
2017-05-07 20:19:00.613 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.rest.RestLogoutFilter              : Filter 'restLogoutFilter' configured successfully
2017-05-07 20:19:00.613 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter      : Initializing filter 'restAuthenticationFilter'
2017-05-07 20:19:00.613 DEBUG --- [ost-startStop-1] g.p.s.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter      : Filter 'restAuthenticationFilter' configured successfully
2017-05-07 20:19:02.731 DEBUG --- [           main] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : setHierarchy() - The following role hierarchy was set: 
2017-05-07 20:19:03.064 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named '' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named '' in your configuration.
```

Here is my ***application.yml*** content:

```
---
grails:
    profile: rest-api
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: ras
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            js: text/javascript
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            all: '*/*'
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8

---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: *******
    password: *******

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ras_dev?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ras_test?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ras?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

***application.groovy***

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'InterceptUrlMap'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName = 'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.failureStatusCode = 401
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/api/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.logout.endpointUrl = '/api/logout'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.useEncryptedJwt = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.privateKeyPath = 'security/private_key.der'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.jwt.publicKeyPath = 'security/public_key.der'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.rendering.authoritiesPropertyName = 'permissions'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.rendering.usernamePropertyName = 'username'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.generation.useSecureRandom = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = false

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    ['/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'], // Stateless chain
    ['/data/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'], // Stateless chain
    ['/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter']   // Traditional chain
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/partials/**',    access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/api/login',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/api/logout',     access: ['isFullyAuthenticated()']],
    [pattern: '/api/validate',   access: ['isFullyAuthenticated()']],
    [pattern: '/**',             access: ['isFullyAuthenticated()']]
]
```

***resources.groovy***

```
import ras.bean.DefaultSecurityEventListener
import ras.auth.DefaultJsonPayloadCredentialsExtractor

beans = {
    credentialsExtractor(DefaultJsonPayloadCredentialsExtractor)
    defaultSecurityEventListener(DefaultSecurityEventListener)
}
```

**grails version:**

```
$ grails --version
| Grails Version: 3.2.6
| Groovy Version: 2.4.7
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_121
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have added following lines to ***logback.groovy***

```
logger("org.springframework.security", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)
logger("grails.plugin.springsecurity", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)
logger("org.pac4j", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'], false)
```

Yet, the console output and **stacktrace.log** file have the same output as posted above

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this error.

Comment: Spring libraries are usually very good about giving you informative stack traces. That does not appear to be the case here. Maybe you can lower the logging level to get better info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix the problem:

***Issue 1:***
I created User Role and UserRole classes manually instead of using

```
grails s2-quickstart com.app-name User Role
```

as described [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#s2-quickstart)

***Issue 2:***
I used the wrong format for chainMap filters. Here is the one that worked for me

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/api/**',    filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'], // Stateless chain
    [pattern: '/data/**',   filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'], // Stateless chain
    [pattern: '/**',        filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter']   // Traditional chain
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Field springSecurityService in com.form.application.UserPasswordEncoderListener required a bean of type 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService' in your configuration
still getting this issue